# How to remove an element in a list which is present another time in the list?(Python)

Tags: python, list

Let's say we have the following list:
`list = ['a','b','c','a']` and we want to remove the second 'a'.
With `list.remove('a')` the first 'a' will be removed.How can we remove the second 'a'?

I tried what I wrote and did not work!Can this be solved with index()?

Comment: No.Just the second 'a'.

Comment: You did not have time to read the answers.